# Multiple input-folders for uglifyjs?

Tags: angularjs, npm, package.json, uglifyjs

I'm trying to set up an uglify task for npm for our AngularJS-project (OS Windows 10). It has several JS files in more than one folder beneath "src/main/webapp/app-basic-an/". It seems to me that I can't just write

```
"scripts": {
    "uglify": "uglifyjs src/main/webapp/app-basic-an/*.js -m -o dist/js/app.js",
    "preuglify": "rimraf dist && mkdir dist\\js"
}
```

cause that still requires all JS-files to be in the specified directory and doesn't include the subdirectories. Isn't there a way to say "include all JS-files beneath the folder src/main/webapp/app-basic-an/"?

Comment: Have you tried using the double glob star? i.e. `src/main/webapp/app-basic-an/**/*.js`

Comment: Yes, that creates an exception: 
`ERROR: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\code\java\dev-basic-an\webapp\src\main\webapp\app-basic-an\**\*.js'`

Comment: I get the same error here on Windows. It seems Windows doesn't support the double glob as mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/1348#issuecomment-256759227), however it does recursively find all `.js` files. using `src/main/webapp/app-basic-an/**/*.js` here on macOS. Perhaps try installing and using [recursive-uglifyjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-uglifyjs) instead, or specify each path separately as the comment in the link suggests.